# Fold on Option vs Fold on Collection

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

In Scala, to express this:

```
val opt:Option[String] = Some("a")
if(opt.isEmpty) "" else opt.get
```

you can use this `fold` pattern on `Options`:

```
opt.fold("")(_)
```

However `fold` on collections behaves differently. How can I achieve the same for collections, without having to write:

```
case class Container(description: String, collection: Seq)
val col = Seq()
if(col.nonEmpty) {
    Some(Container("some description", col))
} else {
    None
}
```

In other words, how can I *elegantly* return `Some()` collection only when it is not empty?

Comment: Did you try `headOption`? Or `headOption.map(whatevergoeshere)`

Comment: Also, `if(opt.isEmpty) "" else opt.get` would be more idiomatic with `opt.getOrElse("")`

Comment: Why is an `if/else` not "elegant"? To me it's perfectly find. If you don't want `if/else` for some reason, here's one way: `Some(col).filter(_.nonEmpty).map(c => Container("some description", c))`

Comment: In what way would that behavior be the same as `fold` on `Option`?

Comment: Because `Some(col).filter(_.nonEmpty)` is basically `if (col.nonEmpty) Some(col) else None`. Then, you `map` that over your `Container` constructor, which transforms only the `Some` case, which means it is the same as `if (col.nonEmpty) { val c = col; Some(Container("some description", c)) } else None`, which, as you can see, is the same as your "inelegant" snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, that your examples for `Option` and `Seq` aren't equivalent: in the former case, the result is the value that was *inside* the `Option` or an empty string, while in the latter case, you end up returning the *collection itself*, not its contents.

You can do an equivalent of what you did with `Option` with a `fold` on collections too, depending on how you want to deal with the multiple values in the collection. For example:

```
seqOfStrings.foldLeft("") { _ + _ }
```

would concatenate all of the strings in the collection into one long string (you could get the same result with `seqOfStrings.mkString`). Note, that this uses `foldLeft` rather than `fold`, because the former is (supposed to be) parallelizable, and is not guaranteed to process the results in order. Here is an example with `fold`:

```
 seqOfInts.fold(0) { _ + _ }
```

This is, of course, the same as `seqOfInts.sum`

The idea of `fold` (left/right) is combining ("folding") all the elements of a collection into a single value. `Option` is a special case, because it can only ever contain a single element, so the transformer function does not need to take two arguments, and looks a lot like the (opposite of) `getOrElse` - thus your confusion.

What you are trying to do with the collection is not really a use case for fold. You could use `headOption` for that as other answers suggested, or, better yet, pattern match:

```
  col match {
     case Seq() => None
     case x => Some(Container("some description", x))
  }
```

You could wrap it into the companion object, to look prettier:

```
  object Container {
     def apply[T](seq: Seq[T]) = seq match {
        case Seq() => None
        case s => Container("some description", x))
     }
  }
```

Now, you can just do `Container(seq)` elsewhere.

Comment: This is very nice, I think the container companion object is the most elegant solution to the problem. Thank you!
Other than that, I think its a bit silly that there are 2 functions that bear the same name but a different behaviour based on context...

Comment: @mirosval I am not sure what you mean by "different behavior". The behavior is actually exactly the same: return the initial value if container is empty, apply the transformation to contents otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation from `fold` is wrong, it is not about `Option`s it is about working with collection and it works with `Option` because they are also collections.

With `fold` you are providing a start value with first parameter and providing a function which will be applied to collection.

About your question:
Code you shared looks fine, but if you **really** want to map some option you can use `headOption` and map it to value you want but this won't make your code more elegant or clear

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit shorter, although also not really elegant:

```scala
Option(col.nonEmpty).collect { case true => Container("some description", col) }
```

Or, but IMO even uglier (I just saw that Hüseyin suggested it as well):

```scala
col.headOption.map(Container("some description", col))
```